# Display CPS in the KeyStrokesMod.. Minecraft PvP Client

Tags: minecraft

I want the CPS (clicks per second) to be displayed on my KeyStrokesMod at RMB and LMB when I click.
Does anyone have the code?
Would be very happy.

My code: https://gist.github.com/ScopeOut/231fcfff3a56ebb1a61e2e49844cd391

[KeyStrokesMod](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQ8sI.png)

Comment: I've already written a sketch here: https://gist.github.com/ScopeOut/bc5b2bfe4cb31fb8765cedd321b00f52